# Program flow not affected by forward declaration

Tags: c++

Here is the example of my forward declaration code which is not working:

```
void Register();
void Menu();

void Register() {
    string username, password, hospitalname;
    ofstream file;
    file.open("Hospital Creds.txt");
    cout << "Hospital Name: ";
    cin >> hospitalname;
    cout << "Username: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Password: ";
    cin >> password;
    cout << endl;

    file << hospitalname << endl;
    file << username << endl;
    file << password << endl;

    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    Menu();
}

void Menu() {
    int choice;
    cout << " 1. Register Hospital " << endl;
    cout << " 2. Register Donor " << endl;
    cout << " 3. Exit " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a number of your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        Register();
        break;
    }
}

void main() {
    Menu();
}
```

It's like this, when the program runs, it goes to the Menu(), then when selected, it goes to Register(), but when it wanna call back the function Menu(), the program exited. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Is that all the code? What is the "when selected" you mention? If that actually is all your code, it is infinite recursion that will blow up the stack and should print some form of error message telling you this. If there is more code, please post it.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with forward declaration.   You're using recursion - functions calling themselves.  `Menu()` calls `Register()` which calls `Menu()` which calls `Register()` ad infinitum.    If you somehow force one of those calls to return (with code you haven't shown), each of those recursively called functions returns, and then `main()` returns so the program ends.    Also, in C++, `main()` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: @KenY-N Edited, please help with my error, thanks

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look.

Comment: Turn on compiler optimization and you have a chance that it optimizes tail recursion. But **don't rely on that**.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `Menu()` from `Register()`, the calling chain is never ending. The function are nested *too* deep. You're soon blowing up the call stack.

In practice, when I write a menu system, I never call previous-level functions from any function. Instead I use a loop to run the main menu infinitely, so I can keep my function call relationship like a tree.

```
void Sub1() {
    // Prompt for input
    if (option == 0) {
        return; // End the call tree
    }
    else if (option == 1) {
        Sub11();
    }
    else if (option == 2) {
        Sub12();
    }
    ...
}

int MainMenu() {
    // Prompt for input
    if (option == 0) {
        return 0; // Quit program
    }
    else if (option == 1) {
        Sub1();
    }
    else if (option == 2) {
        Sub2();
    }
}
....

int main() {
    while (MainMenu() != 0);
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/iBug/CGadgets/blob/master/MyVaultManager/main.c)'s a sample project that I wrote. Note how I arranged the `main()` function.